# Grammar, the construction "more talking + verb+ing"

Tags: sentence-construction

Are the following sentences grammatical:

- The teacher didn't come more talking about giving a lecture.
- I ain't be there more talking about playing with the team.

Answer (score 1):

I think the format you're looking for is "talking more about". The verb "talk" should agree with the subject so sentence one might look like this: " The teacher didn't talk more about giving a lecture". The second sentence might look like this: "I can't (or won't) talk about playing with the team". Maybe the preposition "about" is throwing you off? Verbs in the predicate of a sentence following the word "about" are in -ing form.
 Some examples:

She was thinking about joining the club.

He was complaining about going to the library.

Jerry was bragging about flying to Rome.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with these constructions per se:

- more talking about giving
- more talking about playing

But you haven't used them properly in your sentences. Here are two examples where they are used correctly:

- The teacher didn't need more talking about giving a lecture. She had heard enough already.
- There won't be any more talking about playing with the team. I've decided to retire.